# Wrong block type read - Minecraft Spigot 1.16.3 Plugin

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a plugin that uses fetch and save block type using
`getBlockData().getAsString()`.

I have a problem when retrieving the block type for "*Shulker Box*" and "*Purple Shulker Box*".

---

The engine is 1.16.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.

Plugin written for 1.16.3.

---

When I use `Location.getBlock().getType()` for "*Shulker Box*" it returns "***LEGACY_PURPLE_SHULKER_BOX***" and for "*Purple Shulker Box*" it is "***LEGACY_AIR***".

But, `Location..getBlock().getBlockData().getAsString()` already works correctly. For "*Shulker Box*" it returns "***minecraft:shulker_box[facing=up]***" and for "*Purple Shulker Box*" it is "***minecraft:purple_shulker_box[facing=up]***"

In my plugin before saving the block type I used IF - for check the block is air (`Location.getBlock().getType() != Material.AIR`), if it is not air then I save *BLOCK DATA*.
Unfortunately in this case it doesn't work because the block is detected as air.

Please help me how to solve this problem?

I checked some other SHULKER BOX types and this problem is only with "Shulker Box",

Comment: I know that I can change this check in IF to "Location..getBlock().getBlockData().getAsString()" but how can I do it another way and why does it happen? Is it an engine error or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show your `plugin.yml` file ?

Comment: @Elikill58 in plygin.yml for my plugin i have only information about name, main, version and list of my commands and permissions

Answer (score 1):

Legacy items are used on 1.13+ server when plugin don't indicate the `api-version`.

Such as explained in the [spigotmc doc](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/plugin-yml/), you should add in your `plugin.yml` file :

```
api-version: 1.16
```